# Magento2 around method in plugin to save extra field data in newsletter

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I am new to magento 2 and i would like to add extra field to newsletter so i created a module with plugin to call aroundsubscribe method to save the new field data while subscription but i am unable to do so.

Plugin class is

```
namespace Microwebby\Micro\Module\Plugin\Newsletter;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(

    Http $request
  ) {

    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {
    $result = $proceed($email);
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {
      $subscriber_country = $this->request->getPost('subscriber_country');

      $subject->setCSubscriber_country($subscriber_country);

      try {
        $subject->save();
      }catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

In system.log i can see the trace

```
Microwebby\Micro\Module\Plugin\Newsletter\Subscriber->aroundSubscribe(Object(Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'rashidtahir05@g...')
```

Anything else needed to help please mention so that i can provide you.

I want to add extra field to newsletter subscription form.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
namespace Microwebby\Micro\Module\Plugin\Newsletter;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Subscriber
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function aroundSubscribe(
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $email
    )
    {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $subscriber_country = $this->request->getPost('subscriber_country');
            if($subscriber_country) {
                $subject->loadByEmail($email);

                if (!$subject->getId()) {
                    $subject->setSubscriberConfirmCode($subject->randomSequence());
                }

                $isConfirmNeed = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ) == 1 ? true : false;
                $isOwnSubscribes = false;

                $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()
                    && $this->customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() == $email;

                if (!$subject->getId() || $subject->getStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
                    || $subject->getStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
                ) {
                    if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
                        // if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
                        $isOwnSubscribes = $isSubscribeOwnEmail;
                        if ($isOwnSubscribes == true) {
                            $subject->setStatus(\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                        } else {
                            $subject->setStatus(\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $subject->setStatus(\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                    }
                    $subject->setSubscriberEmail($email);
                }

                if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
                    try {
                        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
                        $subject->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
                        $subject->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
                    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                        $subject->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                        $subject->setCustomerId(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    $subject->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                    $subject->setCustomerId(0);
                }

                $subject->setStatusChanged(true);
                $subject->setSubscriberCountry($subscriber_country);
                try {
                    $subject->save();
                    if ($isConfirmNeed === true
                        && $isOwnSubscribes === false
                    ) {
                        $subject->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
                    } else {
                        $subject->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
                    }
                    return $subject->getStatus();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        return $proceed($email);
    }
}
```

Clear magento cache.

Comment: Still the same result its seems that aroundSubscribe is not called how to find this although system.log as i posted in first post showing about this.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: @pearl_123 did you try last updated answer? It's work for you?

Comment: No it's not working  getting error "
Something went wrong with the subscription." and my custom fields are not stored in database